# Activity doesn't start in ICS , App works perfectly on Motorola Milestone(2.1)

Tags: android, performance

I am making an app which shows list of installed apps, and on item click shows permission. Also, it runs in background and starts on device start. It works perfectly on Motorola Milestone( Android 2.1) but when tested on Sony Xperia(ICS) , the list doesn't get clicked and hence the activity which shows permission is not displayed.

LogCat doesn't show anything in error mode.

MainActivity

```
package com.example.appslist;

import java.util.List;
import com.example.appslist.adapter.ApkAdapter;
import com.example.appslist.app.AppData;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.example.backgroundapp.BackgroundService;






public class ApkListActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    PackageManager packageManager;
    public static boolean isService = false;





    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        startService(new Intent(ApkListActivity.this,BackgroundService.class));
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
        isService = true;


        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> packageList = packageManager
                .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        ListView mylistview= (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mylistview.setAdapter(new ApkAdapter(this, packageList, packageManager));
        mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }





    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long row) {
        super.onResume();
        stopService(new Intent(ApkListActivity.this,
                BackgroundService.class));

        PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) parent
                .getItemAtPosition(position);
        AppData appData = (AppData) getApplication();
        appData.setPackageInfo(packageInfo);

        Intent appInfo = new Intent(ApkListActivity.this, ApkInfo.class);
        startActivity(appInfo);
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.appslist"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:name=".app.AppData">

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.appslist.ApkListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ApkInfo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_apk_info" >
        </activity>

      <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".BackgroundService" />

      <receiver 
          android:enabled="true" 
          android:name="com.example.appslist.BootUpReceiver"
        >

        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
``</receiver>







</application>


    </manifest>
```

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

Are you still having this issue?  If so, have you tried running on other Android 4.X+ devices to see if it works?  If it's an Xperia specific issue then let me know and I can help dig into it further.  Also if it is Xperia specific which device model are you testing with?

Answer (score 0):

`PackageInfo` implements `Parcelable` why not pass it as an intent extra to your `ApkInfo` activity instead of odd implementation of extending the `Application` class to store that data.

Also I don't understand what you are doing here with starting a service and a main activity in you `onCreate` and then stopping the service on a click :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    startService(new Intent(ApkListActivity.this,BackgroundService.class));
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
    isService = true;
...
```

Comment: The service is for running the app in background. My AppData class is used for getting the permissions. I cant understand why it is not working as desired on ICS , Can you suggest changes ?

Comment: @Prax I don't know what you mean by "run the app in the background" or why you are starting an activity in an `onCreate` of another activity. Try what I said above, remove the starting of service and activity in the oncreate and send the `PackageInfo` as intent extra then post the edited code with the error you are getting.