# ListView doesn't respond to clicks in ICS : App works unusally in ICS device

Tags: android, performance

I am making an app which shows list of installed apps, and on item click shows permission. Also, it runs in background and starts on device start.

When tested on Motorola Milestone it worked perfectly. But in Xperia (ICS), following problems:

1. Listview item doesnt respond to clicks at all.
2. App keeps running in background only, doesn't resume when I tried switching to it through the task manager.
3. Permissions cant be displayed as the listview item is not getting clicked.

I have read its a common problem that an app works differently in other versions of android. What should I do to make my app work as desired.

Main Activity

```
package com.example.appslist;

import java.util.List;
import com.example.appslist.adapter.ApkAdapter;
import com.example.appslist.app.AppData;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.example.backgroundapp.BackgroundService;

public class ApkListActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    PackageManager packageManager;
    public static boolean isService = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        startService(new Intent(ApkListActivity.this,BackgroundService.class));
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
        isService = true;
        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> packageList = packageManager
                .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        ListView mylistview= (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mylistview.setAdapter(new ApkAdapter(this, packageList, packageManager));
        mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

         }
        @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long row) {

          super.onResume();
          stopService(new Intent(ApkListActivity.this,
                  BackgroundService.class));

        PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) parent
                .getItemAtPosition(position);
        AppData appData = (AppData) getApplication();
        appData.setPackageInfo(packageInfo);

        Intent appInfo = new Intent(ApkListActivity.this, ApkInfo.class);
        startActivity(appInfo);
    }
}
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.appslist"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:name="com.example.appslist.app.AppData">

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.appslist.ApkListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ApkInfo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_apk_info" >
        </activity>

      <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".BackgroundService" />

      <receiver 
          android:enabled="true" 
          android:name="com.example.appslist.BootUpReceiver"
        >

        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>







    </application>


</manifest>
```

Logcat(error mode)

```
04-22 12:07:16.155: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Inside mad_at_handler_send_FD and the command is: AT*EHSTACT=1
04-22 12:07:16.155: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Got error response: 
04-22 12:07:16.155: E/MAD(1809): OK
04-22 12:07:17.557: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[brand]
04-22 12:07:17.557: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[group-visible]
04-22 12:07:17.557: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[brand]
04-22 12:07:17.557: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[group-visible]
04-22 12:07:17.577: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[brand]
04-22 12:07:17.577: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[group-visible]
04-22 12:07:17.597: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[brand]
04-22 12:07:17.597: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[group-visible]
04-22 12:07:47.125: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Inside mad_at_handler_send_FD and the command is: AT*EHSTACT=2
04-22 12:07:47.135: E/libEGL(1449): validate_display:188 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
04-22 12:07:47.145: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Got error response: 
04-22 12:07:47.145: E/MAD(1809): OK
04-22 12:08:06.554: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Inside mad_at_handler_send_FD and the command is: AT*EHSTACT=1
04-22 12:08:06.564: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Got error response: 
04-22 12:08:06.564: E/MAD(1809): OK
04-22 12:08:08.216: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Inside mad_at_handler_send_FD and the command is: AT*EHSTACT=2
04-22 12:08:08.216: E/libEGL(1449): validate_display:188 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
04-22 12:08:08.226: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Got error response: 
04-22 12:08:08.226: E/MAD(1809): OK
04-22 12:08:08.226: E/MAD(1809): screen_display_process_callback: Screen state same as the last sent, not sending it again
04-22 12:08:23.761: E/HikeMessengerApp(5305): Invalid format
04-22 12:08:23.761: E/HikeMessengerApp(5305): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid access token format.
04-22 12:08:23.761: E/HikeMessengerApp(5305):   at twitter4j.auth.AccessToken.<init>(Unknown Source)
04-22 12:08:23.761: E/HikeMessengerApp(5305):   at com.bsb.hike.HikeMessengerApp.a(Unknown Source)
04-22 12:08:23.761: E/HikeMessengerApp(5305):   at com.bsb.hike.HikeMessengerApp.onCreate(Unknown Source)
04-22 12:08:23.761: E/HikeMessengerApp(5305):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
04-22 12:08:23.761: E/HikeMessengerApp(5305):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3978)
04-22 12:08:23.761: E/HikeMessengerApp(5305):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-22 12:08:23.761: E/HikeMessengerApp(5305):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-22 12:08:23.761: E/HikeMessengerApp(5305):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 12:08:23.761: E/HikeMessengerApp(5305):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 12:08:23.761: E/HikeMessengerApp(5305):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
04-22 12:08:23.761: E/HikeMessengerApp(5305):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 12:08:23.761: E/HikeMessengerApp(5305):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 12:08:23.761: E/HikeMessengerApp(5305):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
04-22 12:08:23.761: E/HikeMessengerApp(5305):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
04-22 12:08:23.761: E/HikeMessengerApp(5305):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 12:08:23.831: E/HikeMqttManager(5305): Trying to connect
04-22 12:09:50.125: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Inside mad_at_handler_send_FD and the command is: AT*EHSTACT=1
04-22 12:09:50.135: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Got error response: 
04-22 12:09:50.135: E/MAD(1809): OK
04-22 12:09:50.596: E/InputDispatcher(1819): channel '418dd0b0 com.example.appslist/com.example.appslist.ApkListActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-22 12:09:51.857: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[brand]
04-22 12:09:51.887: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[group-visible]
04-22 12:10:21.156: E/libEGL(1449): validate_display:188 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
04-22 12:10:21.166: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Inside mad_at_handler_send_FD and the command is: AT*EHSTACT=2
04-22 12:10:21.186: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Got error response: 
04-22 12:10:21.186: E/MAD(1809): OK
04-22 12:10:21.206: E/MAD(1809): screen_display_process_callback: Screen state same as the last sent, not sending it again
04-22 12:10:27.152: E/LockScreen(5882): Unable to parse Customfile - IOException
04-22 12:10:37.842: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Inside mad_at_handler_send_FD and the command is: AT*EHSTACT=1
04-22 12:10:37.852: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Got error response: 
04-22 12:10:37.852: E/MAD(1809): OK
04-22 12:10:37.852: E/MAD(1809): screen_display_process_callback: Screen state same as the last sent, not sending it again
04-22 12:10:54.869: E/ATK(5935): Start manully kill!
04-22 12:10:54.879: E/ATK(5935): com.android.vending
04-22 12:10:54.889: E/ATK(5935): com.facebook.katana
04-22 12:10:54.889: E/ATK(5935): com.google.android.apps.plus
04-22 12:10:54.889: E/ATK(5935): com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware
04-22 12:10:54.889: E/ATK(5935): com.bsb.hike
04-22 12:10:54.899: E/ATK(5935): com.google.android.apps.maps
04-22 12:10:54.899: E/ATK(5935): com.sonyericsson.updatecenter
04-22 12:10:54.899: E/ATK(5935): com.sonyericsson.androidapp.storefront
04-22 12:10:54.899: E/ATK(5935): com.sonyericsson.music
04-22 12:10:54.909: E/ATK(5935): com.cool.fonts.texting.galaxy.changer
04-22 12:10:54.909: E/ATK(5935): com.viber.voip
04-22 12:10:54.909: E/ATK(5935): com.whatsapp
04-22 12:10:57.751: E/ATK(5935): Start manully kill!
04-22 12:11:10.194: E/HikeMessengerApp(6103): Invalid format
04-22 12:11:10.194: E/HikeMessengerApp(6103): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid access token format.
04-22 12:11:10.194: E/HikeMessengerApp(6103):   at twitter4j.auth.AccessToken.<init>(Unknown Source)
04-22 12:11:10.194: E/HikeMessengerApp(6103):   at com.bsb.hike.HikeMessengerApp.a(Unknown Source)
04-22 12:11:10.194: E/HikeMessengerApp(6103):   at com.bsb.hike.HikeMessengerApp.onCreate(Unknown Source)
04-22 12:11:10.194: E/HikeMessengerApp(6103):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
04-22 12:11:10.194: E/HikeMessengerApp(6103):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3978)
04-22 12:11:10.194: E/HikeMessengerApp(6103):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-22 12:11:10.194: E/HikeMessengerApp(6103):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-22 12:11:10.194: E/HikeMessengerApp(6103):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 12:11:10.194: E/HikeMessengerApp(6103):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 12:11:10.194: E/HikeMessengerApp(6103):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
04-22 12:11:10.194: E/HikeMessengerApp(6103):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 12:11:10.194: E/HikeMessengerApp(6103):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 12:11:10.194: E/HikeMessengerApp(6103):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
04-22 12:11:10.194: E/HikeMessengerApp(6103):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
04-22 12:11:10.194: E/HikeMessengerApp(6103):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 12:11:10.264: E/HikeMqttManager(6103): Trying to connect
04-22 12:11:41.504: E/ServiceLocator(6199): ServiceLocator$VoipServiceConnection.onServiceConnected loc:com.viber.service.VoipConnectorService$LocalBinder@4148d170
04-22 12:11:41.704: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[brand]
04-22 12:11:41.704: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[group-visible]
04-22 12:11:41.714: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[brand]
04-22 12:11:41.714: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[group-visible]
04-22 12:11:43.967: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Inside mad_at_handler_send_FD and the command is: AT*EHSTACT=2
04-22 12:11:43.967: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Got error response: 
04-22 12:11:43.967: E/MAD(1809): OK
04-22 12:11:43.967: E/libEGL(1449): validate_display:188 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
04-22 12:11:56.489: E/Process(1819): Error getting pid for '0'
04-22 12:13:26.817: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Inside mad_at_handler_send_FD and the command is: AT*EHSTACT=1
04-22 12:13:26.817: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Got error response: 
04-22 12:13:26.817: E/MAD(1809): OK
04-22 12:13:28.198: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[brand]
04-22 12:13:28.198: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[group-visible]
04-22 12:13:28.208: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[brand]
04-22 12:13:28.208: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[group-visible]
04-22 12:13:33.263: E/ATK(5935): Start manully kill!
04-22 12:13:33.273: E/ATK(5935): com.sonyericsson.music
04-22 12:13:33.293: E/ATK(5935): com.facebook.katana
04-22 12:13:33.293: E/ATK(5935): com.android.vending
04-22 12:13:33.293: E/ATK(5935): com.whatsapp
04-22 12:13:33.303: E/ATK(5935): com.viber.voip
04-22 12:13:33.303: E/ATK(5935): com.cool.fonts.texting.galaxy.changer
04-22 12:13:33.303: E/ATK(5935): com.sonyericsson.androidapp.storefront
04-22 12:13:33.313: E/ATK(5935): com.bsb.hike
04-22 12:13:59.809: E/ServiceLocator(6667): ServiceLocator$VoipServiceConnection.onServiceConnected loc:com.viber.service.VoipConnectorService$LocalBinder@414a1de0
04-22 12:14:03.483: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Inside mad_at_handler_send_FD and the command is: AT*EHSTACT=2
04-22 12:14:03.493: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Got error response: 
04-22 12:14:03.493: E/MAD(1809): OK
04-22 12:14:03.633: E/libEGL(1449): validate_display:188 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
04-22 12:14:28.567: E/HikeMessengerApp(6844): Invalid format
04-22 12:14:28.567: E/HikeMessengerApp(6844): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid access token format.
04-22 12:14:28.567: E/HikeMessengerApp(6844):   at twitter4j.auth.AccessToken.<init>(Unknown Source)
04-22 12:14:28.567: E/HikeMessengerApp(6844):   at com.bsb.hike.HikeMessengerApp.a(Unknown Source)
04-22 12:14:28.567: E/HikeMessengerApp(6844):   at com.bsb.hike.HikeMessengerApp.onCreate(Unknown Source)
04-22 12:14:28.567: E/HikeMessengerApp(6844):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
04-22 12:14:28.567: E/HikeMessengerApp(6844):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3978)
04-22 12:14:28.567: E/HikeMessengerApp(6844):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-22 12:14:28.567: E/HikeMessengerApp(6844):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-22 12:14:28.567: E/HikeMessengerApp(6844):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 12:14:28.567: E/HikeMessengerApp(6844):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 12:14:28.567: E/HikeMessengerApp(6844):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
04-22 12:14:28.567: E/HikeMessengerApp(6844):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 12:14:28.567: E/HikeMessengerApp(6844):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 12:14:28.567: E/HikeMessengerApp(6844):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
04-22 12:14:28.567: E/HikeMessengerApp(6844):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
04-22 12:14:28.567: E/HikeMessengerApp(6844):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 12:14:28.647: E/HikeMqttManager(6844): Trying to connect
04-22 12:15:36.423: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Inside mad_at_handler_send_FD and the command is: AT*EHSTACT=1
04-22 12:15:36.443: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Got error response: 
04-22 12:15:36.443: E/MAD(1809): OK
04-22 12:15:40.577: E/ATK(5935): Start manully kill!
04-22 12:15:40.587: E/ATK(5935): com.sonyericsson.music
04-22 12:15:40.607: E/ATK(5935): com.facebook.katana
04-22 12:15:40.607: E/ATK(5935): com.bsb.hike
04-22 12:15:40.617: E/ATK(5935): com.sonyericsson.androidapp.storefront
04-22 12:15:40.627: E/ATK(5935): com.cool.fonts.texting.galaxy.changer
04-22 12:15:40.627: E/ATK(5935): com.viber.voip
04-22 12:15:40.627: E/ATK(5935): com.android.vending
04-22 12:15:40.637: E/ATK(5935): com.whatsapp
04-22 12:15:55.802: E/HikeMessengerApp(6973): Invalid format
04-22 12:15:55.802: E/HikeMessengerApp(6973): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid access token format.
04-22 12:15:55.802: E/HikeMessengerApp(6973):   at twitter4j.auth.AccessToken.<init>(Unknown Source)
04-22 12:15:55.802: E/HikeMessengerApp(6973):   at com.bsb.hike.HikeMessengerApp.a(Unknown Source)
04-22 12:15:55.802: E/HikeMessengerApp(6973):   at com.bsb.hike.HikeMessengerApp.onCreate(Unknown Source)
04-22 12:15:55.802: E/HikeMessengerApp(6973):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
04-22 12:15:55.802: E/HikeMessengerApp(6973):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3978)
04-22 12:15:55.802: E/HikeMessengerApp(6973):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-22 12:15:55.802: E/HikeMessengerApp(6973):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-22 12:15:55.802: E/HikeMessengerApp(6973):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 12:15:55.802: E/HikeMessengerApp(6973):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 12:15:55.802: E/HikeMessengerApp(6973):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
04-22 12:15:55.802: E/HikeMessengerApp(6973):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 12:15:55.802: E/HikeMessengerApp(6973):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 12:15:55.802: E/HikeMessengerApp(6973):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
04-22 12:15:55.802: E/HikeMessengerApp(6973):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
04-22 12:15:55.802: E/HikeMessengerApp(6973):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 12:15:55.862: E/HikeMqttManager(6973): Trying to connect
04-22 12:16:10.737: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Inside mad_at_handler_send_FD and the command is: AT*EHSTACT=2
04-22 12:16:10.747: E/libEGL(1449): validate_display:188 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
04-22 12:16:10.747: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Got error response: 
04-22 12:16:10.747: E/MAD(1809): OK
04-22 12:16:10.747: E/MAD(1809): screen_display_process_callback: Screen state same as the last sent, not sending it again
04-22 12:16:26.762: E/ServiceLocator(7069): ServiceLocator$VoipServiceConnection.onServiceConnected loc:com.viber.service.VoipConnectorService$LocalBinder@4149fc00
04-22 12:22:32.169: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Inside mad_at_handler_send_FD and the command is: AT*EHSTACT=1
04-22 12:22:32.189: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Got error response: 
04-22 12:22:32.189: E/MAD(1809): OK
04-22 12:22:32.209: E/MAD(1809): screen_display_process_callback: Screen state same as the last sent, not sending it again
04-22 12:22:34.501: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Inside mad_at_handler_send_FD and the command is: AT*EHSTACT=2
04-22 12:22:34.511: E/libEGL(1449): validate_display:188 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
04-22 12:22:34.511: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Got error response: 
04-22 12:22:34.511: E/MAD(1809): OK
04-22 12:26:24.936: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Inside mad_at_handler_send_FD and the command is: AT*EHSTACT=1
04-22 12:26:24.946: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Got error response: 
04-22 12:26:24.946: E/MAD(1809): OK
04-22 12:26:35.156: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Inside mad_at_handler_send_FD and the command is: AT*EHSTACT=2
04-22 12:26:35.166: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Got error response: 
04-22 12:26:35.166: E/MAD(1809): OK
04-22 12:26:35.166: E/libEGL(1449): validate_display:188 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
04-22 12:28:19.708: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Inside mad_at_handler_send_FD and the command is: AT*EHSTACT=1
04-22 12:28:19.718: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Got error response: 
04-22 12:28:19.718: E/MAD(1809): OK
04-22 12:28:22.501: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[brand]
04-22 12:28:22.501: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[group-visible]
04-22 12:28:22.531: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[brand]
04-22 12:28:22.531: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[group-visible]
04-22 12:28:22.541: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[brand]
04-22 12:28:22.541: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[group-visible]
04-22 12:28:22.551: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[brand]
04-22 12:28:22.551: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[group-visible]
04-22 12:28:22.561: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[brand]
04-22 12:28:22.561: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[group-visible]
04-22 12:28:22.571: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[brand]
04-22 12:28:22.571: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[group-visible]
04-22 12:28:22.581: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[brand]
04-22 12:28:22.581: E/SemcSettingsParser(3941): key not found. key=[group-visible]
04-22 12:28:23.742: E/ATK(5935): Start manully kill!
04-22 12:28:23.762: E/ATK(5935): com.viber.voip
04-22 12:28:23.772: E/ATK(5935): com.facebook.katana
04-22 12:28:23.772: E/ATK(5935): com.sonyericsson.updatecenter
04-22 12:28:23.772: E/ATK(5935): com.google.android.apps.plus
04-22 12:28:23.772: E/ATK(5935): com.android.vending
04-22 12:28:23.772: E/ATK(5935): com.whatsapp
04-22 12:28:23.782: E/ATK(5935): com.cool.fonts.texting.galaxy.changer
04-22 12:28:23.782: E/ATK(5935): com.sonyericsson.androidapp.storefront
04-22 12:28:23.782: E/ATK(5935): com.bsb.hike
04-22 12:28:29.898: E/ServiceLocator(7597): ServiceLocator$VoipServiceConnection.onServiceConnected loc:com.viber.service.VoipConnectorService$LocalBinder@4147e3b8
04-22 12:28:53.941: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Inside mad_at_handler_send_FD and the command is: AT*EHSTACT=2
04-22 12:28:53.951: E/MAD(1809): mad_at_handler_send_FD: Got error response: 
04-22 12:28:53.951: E/MAD(1809): OK
04-22 12:28:53.961: E/libEGL(1449): validate_display:188 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
04-22 12:29:19.016: E/HikeMessengerApp(7891): Invalid format
04-22 12:29:19.016: E/HikeMessengerApp(7891): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid access token format.
04-22 12:29:19.016: E/HikeMessengerApp(7891):   at twitter4j.auth.AccessToken.<init>(Unknown Source)
04-22 12:29:19.016: E/HikeMessengerApp(7891):   at com.bsb.hike.HikeMessengerApp.a(Unknown Source)
04-22 12:29:19.016: E/HikeMessengerApp(7891):   at com.bsb.hike.HikeMessengerApp.onCreate(Unknown Source)
04-22 12:29:19.016: E/HikeMessengerApp(7891):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
04-22 12:29:19.016: E/HikeMessengerApp(7891):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3978)
04-22 12:29:19.016: E/HikeMessengerApp(7891):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-22 12:29:19.016: E/HikeMessengerApp(7891):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-22 12:29:19.016: E/HikeMessengerApp(7891):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 12:29:19.016: E/HikeMessengerApp(7891):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 12:29:19.016: E/HikeMessengerApp(7891):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
04-22 12:29:19.016: E/HikeMessengerApp(7891):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 12:29:19.016: E/HikeMessengerApp(7891):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 12:29:19.016: E/HikeMessengerApp(7891):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
04-22 12:29:19.016: E/HikeMessengerApp(7891):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
04-22 12:29:19.016: E/HikeMessengerApp(7891):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 12:29:19.096: E/HikeMqttManager(7891): Trying to connect
04-22 12:31:55.408: E/dalvikvm(8009): Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$InboxStyle', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.plus.service.AndroidNotification.createDigestNotification$78923c81
```

I was referring [Tutorial](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android/) for getting list of installed apps.I had posted a similar question, someone suggested problem in main ,but it worked perfectly on 2.1.

Please Please help and suggest. :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Activity doesn't start in ICS , App works perfectly on Motorola Milestone(2.1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119700/activity-doesnt-start-in-ics-app-works-perfectly-on-motorola-milestone2-1)

Comment: @IceMAN I only posted the question , but din't get any relevant answer.

Comment: To whoever who down voted the question: If the question is so vague , Why cant I get a single relavant/useful answer :/

Answer (score 0):

if you using button in listview then In your `main.xml` file In list view tag set `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`. hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but there is no button. It is a custom listview using adapter, I haven't used any buttons.

Comment: why you are calling super.onResume() inside onitemclick()...?

Comment: I wanted when the service is resumed, permissions to be displayed, I tried changing it but din't do any good, so kept as it is